# How to simplify $-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to simplify $$-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$$

This is one part of a sum that I need to get all the sums in terms of $x^n$ so that I can compare coefficients to help find a series solution to an ODE. But what I tried was to multiply by $x$ that is in the numerator to get it in terms of $x^n$ but then you are left with this $-(1+x^2)^{-1}$ which I'm not sure how to deal with where comparing coefficients.

It feels like I'm missing something.

Any help?

Comment: $-\frac{x}{1+x^2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$ or $-\frac{x}{1+x^2}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}na_nx^{n-1}$?